# How many maximum number of components can be there in UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I was just wondering, how many components can be added to a `UIPickerView`?

Comment: Theoretically as many as you want...

Comment: You will run out of RAM before you run out of components.

Comment: Well there is a maximum, `NSIntegerMax` since the number of rows is of type `NSInteger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, NSObject inherited objects can hold up to NSUIntegerMax objects (this is the largest value that can be returned from count). On a 32-bit system like the iPhone, that is a little over 4 billion. On a 64-bit system like most Macs/iPhone5S, it is many orders of magnitude higher.

I suspect you will run out of RAM before you hit this CS limit.

Comment: Appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not sure this completely answers the question.  Certainly the component will fail to display in any sort of usable fashion well before the number of components even reaches 100?  I think there's an implied constraint of "and still be usable" when asking about the maximum number of items that can appear in a UI component.